# Hibernate - how to reflect changes in database at runtime?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have an application full of real data. I'd like to provide aministrator interface, who can add new columns, indexes and so on to database tables.

But of course there are already data inserted. Can I somehow dynamically add new fields to mapping classes and remap it on runtime? So I don't have to stop server, recompile, deploy and start it again?

Or is this too low-level thing to do with Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I experimented trying to solve similar problem once, you can only perform a new Configuration#configure during runtime -> build a new SessionFactory out of it -> create new Sessions having the new configuration reflected. This solution worked fine. However, I found no solution how to propagate these changes to an existing SessionFactory instance.

Comment: You can do whatever you want when building a new Configuration, it's flexible. E.g., in my case I even created new .class files (using dynamic compilation routines) & mappings (.hbm.xml - old way, since it's the way application worked), placed them in a classpath, and performed new Configuration().configure. In your case, when you want to add a new columns, you could consider instrumenting your runtime classes (not sure about how that would work, but worth trying, though).

Comment: impressed with your in-memory compilation. must have caused issues with source control etc, but still impressed :)

Comment: @Bohemian Sarcasm? I think we are talking about runtime. In my case these were simple runtime entities mentioned to be defined by end-users, and stored as a simple definition files in an app working directory. Btw, it was not quite in-memory compilation, the stored .java files were compiled using JavaCompiler utility, but I think in-memory should also be possible.

Comment: I agree that it's kind of black magic.. There are other issues. E.g., Configuration#configure will take quite a lot of time to perform (one of the main reasons why we discarded this feature, and another design solution applied). Let us know what you have decided/implemented when it's over :)

Comment: Honestly I don't like the whole idea to let someone mess with database that is already in production (even though it's not mission critical, it's pretty unconvinient) ... I'll sure let you know, maybe I'll pick raw JDBC or summon daemons or what ...

Comment: I picked JDBC after all. This kind of work is too hard to achieve with Hibernate.